# How do I configure my vimrc to use different theme?

Tags: vim, vi

My vimrc is located at /usr/share/vim/vimrc and I have got .vim file for theme I want to use. In which directory I put my .vim theme file and what I change in my vimrc file?
Here is my vimrc file:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd        " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch      " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase     " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase      " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch      " Incremental search
"set autowrite      " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden             " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a        " Enable mouse usage (all modes)
set autoindent
" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

Answer (score 5):

That file is *not* your vimrc: it is a default vimrc that is made available system-wide to make Vim behave in a slightly predictable way. Don't touch it.

The correct location for *your* vimrc is:

```
$HOME/.vimrc
```

and the correct location of *your* config (including colorschemes) is:

```
$HOME/.vim/
```

***NEVER*** do *anything* in `/usr/share/vim/`: your changes won't work reliably or even predictably and they can be overwritten during an update.

Comment: Good catch, totally missed that part. :)

Comment: A lot of the unpredictability with changing the system vimrc is that it is sourced in compatible mode unlike the user vimrc

Answer (score 2):

See `:help :colorscheme`.

You can type `:colo` and then `ctrl-d` to list all available colorschemes.

Put your colorscheme in either `$HOME/.vim/colors` (Unix) or `%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\colors` (Windows).

Example:

Put your colorscheme `foo.vim` into `$HOME/.vim/colors` and then `colorscheme foo` into your vimrc.

Comment: If you are using a 'runtime manager' aka a plugin manager like Pathogen/Vundle/Vim-Plug you should note that if you "install" themes using one, you need to set your colorscheme AFTER the end of the plugin manager's initialization block. For Vim-plug this is ```call plug#end()```, Pathogen just uses ```execute pathogen#infect()``` and Vundle uses ```call vundle#end()```.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim

```
:version
```

You will get:

> System vimrc file: $VIM/vimrc
>   User vimrc file: $HOME/.vimrc

and run:

```
:scriptnames
```

you will get a list of path of your vimrc file:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/vimrc_example.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/mswin.vi
...
```

So you may find that your vimrc file should be under `~/.vimrc`. And like @romainl said never put your own file under `/usr/share/vim`, all changes may be overwritten during the update.